# Multiple Physical Monitors as Different Xorg Displays/Screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display, amd-graphics

I’m trying to setup four displays with each addressable as their own X display or screen. For example, I can run `DISPLAY=:0.0 xclock` and it will show on my primary monitor, but I cannot get `DISPLAY=:0.1 xclock` or `DISPLAY=:1 xclock` to have it show on my other monitors. It seems that all four monitors are under the same display and screen. How can I separate them to address them as separate displays?

For context, I am using xubuntu, but if it is not possible in this xfce, I can choose another Ubuntu distro. It is using AMD RX-427BB built-in Radeon graphics, it is an HP-T730 Thin Client PC.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer i have is to run the whole computer on few virtual machine, one per screen or group of screens, but I hate that solution. The reason is the loss of 2d/3d graphics acceleration and the need to switch the keyboard/mouse input from one machine to the other (by exiting mouse-grab or full-screen or hitting a key macro)